# ¿Como saber en que ruta estoy con react-navigation en react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

Estoy usando un StackNavigation de react-navigation en react-native, pero necesito que mi componente header sea muy personalizado segun la ruta, se colocar el componente heade personalizado, pero no logro obtener el nombre de la ruta en la que estoy o algo que la identifique en el header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Muy fácil, con esta línea:

```
this.props.navigate.state.key
```

Te devolverá un string con el nombre de la ruta actual.